# Why JSON stringify do not parse boolean values

Tags: typescript

I have a game interface with some fields. I need to copy a game object.

My code:

```
console.log(game);
const gameCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(game));
console.log(gameCopy);
```

Result in Original Object:

```
{
    "uuid": "9fe8599c-0560-4633-95a5-b1e7c0f896c4",
    //some fields
    "matchDate": "2022-10-07T09:46:00.000+00:00",
    "groupName": "D",
    "result": null,
    "allowPredictions": true,
    "matchStarted": false,
    "matchFinished": false
}
```

Copied Object:

```
{
    "uuid": "9fe8599c-0560-4633-95a5-b1e7c0f896c4",
    //some fields
    "matchDate": "2022-10-07T09:46:00.000+00:00",
    "groupName": "D",
    "result": null
}
```

As you can see all of the boolean missing after a copy.

My Interface:

```
export interface Game {
  uuid: string;
  firstTeam: Team;
  secondTeam: Team;
  matchDate: string;
  groupName: string;
  result: string;
  predicted: boolean;
  matchStarted: boolean;
  matchFinished: boolean;
  allowPredictions: boolean;
  preidctionFirstTeamGoals: number;
  preidctionSecondTeamGoals: number;
}
```

What I do wrong? Why half of the data are missing and how to fix it?

Comment: I've run your code (https://jsfiddle.net/q7jof1ad/) and it works fine. The copied object still contains the boolean properties. Same result on typescript playground.

Comment: crazy, exact same not work in my project. All boolean fields are not there anymore after copy. Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(gameCopy));`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mre].  Can you provide enough code to reproduce your `game` object?  It's possible those properties exist only on the prototype or are not enumerable or something.  It certainly doesn't have to do with being `boolean`.  So the actual issue is not demonstrated here.